How to setup train/test and evaluation to compare multiple recommender Models?
long story short, I need to compare perfmance of various reccomender models on a dataset. The data contains users and their ratings of some items. I need to compare various approaches (collaborative filtering, content-based etc.) I have trouble in figuring out how to split the data into train/test. I want to evaluate both the rating prediction as well as top-k reccomendations.
My current plan is:

for each User leave 5 ratings out for the test set and leave the rest of the ratings in the training set (all users have at least 20 ratings)
calculate RMSE over the ratings on test set.
calculate NDCG@5 per user for the 5 Items in the test set and average it over all users.

Would you guys consider this a valid approach? Any alternative sugestion will be greatly appreciated.
